# Add a line before a string in a file using awk

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, grep

I want to add a line

```
allow = alaw
```

before a string

```
nat = no
```

in a file `sip.conf` (or any text based file). If `allow = alaw` already exists before `nat = no` it should not be added. And the line should not be added in the two sections immediately after `[general]` and `[providertrunk0]` of the file.

### Example file content:

```
[general]
disallow = all
allow = ulaw
nat = no

[providertrunk0]
disallow = all
allow = ulaw
;allow = alaw
nat = no

secret =
nat = no
progressinband = yes

allow = ulaw
allow = alaw
nat = no
progressinband = yes

disallow = all
allow = ulaw
nat = no
progressinband = yes
```

After changes it would be

```
[general]
disallow = all
allow = ulaw
nat = no

[providertrunk0]
disallow = all
allow = ulaw
;allow = alaw
nat = no

secret =
allow = alaw
nat = no
progressinband = yes

allow = ulaw
allow = alaw
nat = no
progressinband = yes

disallow = all
allow = ulaw
allow = alaw
nat = no
progressinband = yes
```

**My attempt**

I tried want to exclude the whole process for `[general]` and `[providertrunk0]` section, but apply in whole file, using `'/general/,/providertrunk0/{next}'` like this:

```
awk -v add="allow = alaw" '/general/,/providertrunk0/{next} /^nat = no$/&&lastLine!=add{print add}{lastLine=$0}1' sip.conf '
```

but its not giving correct output.

Comment: @EdMorton  I modified my qsn. I shared expected output as   "After changes it would be"

Comment: You say "If allow = alaw already exists before nat = no it should not be added." but in the last paragraph of the sample output, that's exactly what you do.

Comment: What are "the two sections immediately after [general] and [providertrunk0]" -- The paragraph that starts `secret =` looks like the 2nd section. Am I wrong?

Comment: yes , you are right @glennjackman .  Ed Morton please explain how its working

Comment: Please disregard my first comment, I did not notice the difference in spelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS=OFS="\n"
    skip["[general]"]
    skip["[providertrunk0]"]
    add = "allow = alaw"
    tgt = "nat = no"
}
!($1 in skip) {
    for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {
        if ( ($i != add) && ($(i+1) == tgt) ) {
            $i = $i OFS add
        }
    }
}
{ print }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
[general]
disallow = all
allow = ulaw
nat = no

[providertrunk0]
disallow = all
allow = ulaw
;allow = alaw
nat = no

secret =
allow = alaw
nat = no
progressinband = yes

allow = ulaw
allow = alaw
nat = no
progressinband = yes

disallow = all
allow = ulaw
allow = alaw
nat = no
progressinband = yes
```

Setting RS to null puts awk in paragraph mode (see `RS = ""` in https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multiple-Line) so your input is split into multi-line records separated by blank lines. Setting ORS="\n\n" ensures you get a blank line between records when output. Setting FS and OFS to "\n" means that the record is split into fields. So then the rest of the code is trivial as you can just compare specific fields (lines) with the values mentioned in your question. `skip[]` is just the name I made up for any array where I store the first-field (first-line) strings I want to ignore for further processing in that array and then for each record test if the first field/line of the record is in the array and, if so, skip processing it.

Comment: thanks a lot for the valuable efforts. Aboce script is working fine.  Could you please explain  how its working like RS,  ORS, FS ,  skip.

Comment: You're welcome, I just added an explanation.